# Cant DEBUG instrumentation tests in some projects

Tags: android, kotlin, cucumber, android-jetpack-compose

I see in result:

```
Test run failed to complete. Instrumentation run failed due to Process crashed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':GraphKit:connectedDebugAndroidTest'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///Users/renetik/Development/sequenex/android/graphkit-android/GraphKit/build/reports/androidTests/connected/index.html

* Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

In report I see:

```
Test run failed to complete. Instrumentation run failed due to Process crashed.
```

In logcat I see just:

```
Crash of app com.sequenex.graphkit.test running instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.sequenex.graphkit.test/com.sequenex.graphkit.test.CucumberTestRunner}
```

I use cucumber test runner and running it by right click on feature files in resources and Run/Dubeg "Tests in features". This works fine for run but fails just for debug what makes my development sad story, as I debug by console prints. I believe this can be some upstream bug but not sure as I dont see reports of it.

I would like to know where I can put that --stacktrace, --info, --debug, --scan params to get more info about reasons.